# how to use release keystore signature in debug mode in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a keystore file generated for release of an app in flutter.
file is stored at "D:/release.keystore".
and app is already released to playstore with that file.
how to use that "release.keystore" file while debugging the app for future updates.
I want to use release keystore signature in debug mode in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to do this. I'm guessing you're trying to recreate a production issue, conduct integration testing, or somehow mimic the production app.

However, it's important to note that using a release keystore for debugging purposes is not a recommended practice. Nevertheless, here are the steps you can follow:

1. Open your **android/app/build.gradle**
2. Locate the **buildTypes** block, which contains configurations for
   different build types such as debug and release.
3. Inside the buildTypes block, you can add the keystore details for
   the debug build type. Below is an example

:

```
android {
    // ...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // ... existing release signing config
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('path/to/your/release.keystore')
            storePassword 'your_keystore_password'
            keyAlias 'your_key_alias'
            keyPassword 'your_key_password'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't works. it also shows different signature.